# Ideas on deploying a Social Game's multiple branches

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, git, version-control, continuous-integration

I'm struggling with the following scenario:  We're a team that's developing an experimental social game on Facebook.  Our team is scattered over the world and many times we have would like to have an automated mechanism to deploy a feature branch directly after a commit.

I guess this is something akin to a CI solution but heavier.  For out case (we are using git) we want developers to be able to "automagically" deploy their feature branch to facebook for skype-centric discussions around the latest developments.

Our front-end is Flash, and our backend is Google App Engine. Our CDN is Amazon S3.

Any ideas?

~ Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a Continuous Integration solution, such as Atlassian Bamboo, Jenkins or Hudson.

I would recommend the following setup (this would definitely work with Bamboo):

1. You create a build/test/deploy plan for the main branch.
2. Duplicate this plan for each dev. branch of each team member, and
   adjust the repository settings to clone from the corresponding
   branch.
3. Configure the build plans to trigger on commit or perform a nightly
   build.